# Preloader not shown one or more http service call simultaneously using httpInterceptors?

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I want to implement the global pre-loader concept in angular using httpInterceptors, its not working suppose if two http service call simultaneously called, 'finalize' will trigger only after one or more http api calls end, but its not happened, the preloader is also not shown correctly, it hide after first api call finished. Please suggest what i missed and tell me how to handle it. Is this the right place to handle the global error and preloader concept?

app.component.html

```
<preloader [loading]="appService.loading"></preloader>
```

app.component.ts:

```js
const url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1";
const url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/2";
forkJoin(
        this.http.get(url1),
        this.http.get(url2),
    ).subscribe(console.log);
```

HttpserviceInterceptor:

```js
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppCommonService } from './app.common.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpserviceInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private appService: AppCommonService,
        private notification: NotificationsWrapperService,
    ) {}
    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.appService.showPreLoader()
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            //tslint:disable-next-line: no-empty
            tap(() => {
            }, (error: any) => {
                this.notification.error(error);
            }),
            finalize(() => this.appService.hidePreLoader()),
        );
    }
}
```

AppCommonService:

```js
public showPreloader(): void {
    //this.showPreloader$.next(true);
    this.loading = true;
}

public hidePreLoader(): void {
    //this.showPreloader$.next(false);
    this.loading = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose that you perform two requests. The first one takes one second to complete and the second one takes 5 seconds. Based on the code you provided the flow of the loader will be the following.

- First request is performed and `this.loading` is set to true
- Second request is performed and `this.loading` is set to true again
- First requests finishes, and `this.loading` is set to false (wrong)
- Second requests finishes, and `this.loading` is set to false

To make the loader appear as long as a request is active, you should try to keep the number of the requests that are currently performed by the web browser. Lets assume that you initialize a private integer named `currentNumberOfRequests`, and set it's value to 0.

So when a requests is performed, you should always set the {this.loading} flag to true and increase the `this.currentNumberOfRequests` by 1, and when a requests succeeds or fails (ideally in the finally clause), you should decrease the `this.currentNumberOfRequests` by 1. Now, if the `this.currentNumberOfRequests` is 0 you should hide the loader.